# tag values of buttons are changing everytime when scrolling table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a table view and added buttons dynamically to the cells using FOR loop. I have set the tags also. But the problem is the tag values of the buttons are changing when i scroll the table view.

Can someone please tell me how to rectify this problem.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Use a custom UITableViewCell subclass instead of tags. Tags are bad :(

Comment: Probably you are not aware of the face that most of elements are reused. But show us the code.

Comment: yourbtn.tag = indexpath.row
Use above code

Comment: you don't need a for loop. it's enough to add it @ cellforrowatindexpath delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use for loop. just put

```
yourbtn.tag=indexpath.row
```

in cellforrowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

dont use for loop for creating button on table view cell.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath Create button like this

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 2, 100, 40)];
btn.tag = indexpth.row ;
[btn setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];[btn addTarget:selfaction:@selector(btnTouched:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];[btn release];



     -(IBAction)btnTouched:(UIButton*)sender
        {
             switch (sender.tag) 
             {
                case 0:{// This is 0 tag button do something here
             } break;
             case 1:
             {
                // This is 1 tag button do something here
             } break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are changing because the table view is reusing the uitablewviewcells. Also, take a look at this [link](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html)